# combined WHERE clauses subqueries

Tags: sql

New to SQL and having difficulty setting up a select statement.

I have the 2 following tables and I am trying to query all data that has the width and the contextual data that corresponds to that same observation_id. My current query produces the query table shown.

**Current Query Code**

```
SELECT value, trait_name, observation_id
FROM measurements AS m
INNER JOIN
traits AS t
ON m.trait_id = t.trait_id
WHERE trait_name = 'width' OR trait_class = 'contextual'
```

How do I only return the contextual data when it has the same observation_id as the trait_name I selected? The desired output are the rows in the query table colored in green.

[image]

Comment: I do not see "observation_id FROM initial where clause" ?

Comment: @Luuk, was just some pseduo query I deleted since it confuses the question. Hope, it's clearer now.

Comment: You mean you only want to show records that have 'width' and 'temperature' with the same observation_id.

Comment: Correct. The query code above produces the query table in the image. I want just the rows in green and not the yellow rows which are included because of my OR statement. This is just a simple example of my database which has many traits with trait_class organismal or contextual. I will be querying on the traits and want to gather all contextual traits that have the same observation_id as returned by my WHERE trait_name = 'x'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understant your question is you want to display the observations only for trait_name='width', but both for trait_name='width' or trait_class='contextual'. The subquery to get the observation is

```
SELECT observation_id 
FROM measurements m
INNER JOIN traits t
ON m.trait_id=t.trait_id
AND t.trait_name='width'
```

and then the full query would look like

```
SELECT value, trait_name, observation_id
FROM measurements AS m
INNER JOIN
traits AS t
ON m.trait_id = t.trait_id
WHERE (trait_name = 'width' OR trait_class = 'contextual')
AND observation_id IN
    (SELECT observation_id 
    FROM measurements m
    INNER JOIN traits t
    ON m.trait_id=t.trait_id
    AND t.trait_name='width')
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this more efficient? Without the subquery, my query executes in 0.141 seconds. With the subquery, it executes in 61.844 seconds. When I change the trait_name to a trait that has no corresponding contextual data i.e. the subquery only returns a few observation ids, it executes in 0.375 sec

Comment: @Patrick, on which SQL version are you running those queries and what is the number or records in each of the tables? My guess is some indexes could help. You could try an index on trait_id on both tables, one on trait_name in table traits.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT value, trait_name, observation_id
FROM measurements AS m
INNER JOIN
traits AS t
ON m.trait_id = t.trait_id
WHERE ( trait_name = 'width' OR trait_class = 'contextual' )
 and observation_id in (select observation_id 
                          from measurements m1
                          inner join measurements m2 on m1.observation_id=m2.observation_id
                                                    and m2.trait_name='temperature'
                          where m1.trait_name='width')
```

The sub-query will select all `observation_id` that have a 'temperature' and a 'width'

Comment: In place of m2.trait_name = 'temperature', I replaced with m2.trait_class = 'contextual'. Should that work to capture all traits that are contextual? My above example only had temperature, but my db has many others.

Comment: As long as  you are happy with the results, you can change anything....  

Comment: I'm getting: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column m1.trait_name in where clause . Best guess is because trait_name is not in the measurements table, it's in the traits table